# How can I detect rel="noreferrer" support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, referrer, referrals

Is there any way I can detect the support for rel="noreferrer" with Javascript?

```
<a href="http://example.com" rel="noreferrer">link without referral</a>
```

**Solution** - $.browser is deprecated, and it may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.

```
var is_webkit = $.browser.webkit;
if(is_webkit) {
    alert('supports rel="noreferrer"');
}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas you might want to check the solution i posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is none. Referrer headers are outside the domain of JavaScript.

If it's particularly important, you could check whether the browser (`navigator.userAgent`) is one known to support or not support `noreferrer`.

Comment: i know this is deprecated, but still works for my purpose: var is_webkit = $.browser.webkit;

Comment: This is wrong. I detect noreferrer support in hotlink.js (https://github.com/eligrey/hotlink.js/blob/master/hotlink.js) with iframes.

Answer (score 17):

I detect noreferrer support by creating a hidden iframe with a `name` attribute, and then I create an `<a rel="noreferrer">` link with its `target` attribute equal to the iframe's `name` attribute, and have the link point to any resource on the current domain. Linking to `about:blank` also works, but it has problems in Firefox and IE, so you should instead link to an intentionally blank file on your server. After the resource is loaded in the iframe, check that `[the iframe].contentDocument.referrer === ""`. If this is true, `noreferrer` is supported.

An example of my implementation is available in [hotlink.js](https://github.com/eligrey/hotlink.js/). Specifically, see [on_ready](https://github.com/eligrey/hotlink.js/blob/master/hotlink.js#L108).