# Catching event when following a link

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events, keyboard-events

I am trying to track clicks on an external link (without using a "redirect page").

How can I capture an event when a user follows a link, regardless of whether the user:

1. Left clicks on the link
2. Right clicks on the link and open it in a new window
3. Use the keyboard to activate the link
4. Is there other ways to activate a link?

The onClick event only applies to the first.

If setting `href="javascript:fireEventAndFollowLink()"` the user will not be able to open the link in a new window (2), so this is not a solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A link can be triggered in some ways (assuming modern browsers, see foot note):

1. Left click

   - For `<a target="_blank">` or `<a target="_new">`, the page will be loaded in a **new tab**.
   - When the user presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, the page will be loaded in a **new tab**.
   - When the user presses <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, the page will be loaded in a **new window**.
   - For other `target` values, the link can be loaded in the **current screen** or **another frame**.
2. Midde click

   - The page will be loaded in a new tab, regardless of the modifier keys.
3. Right click
   **This method is incredibly hard, if not impossible to fully implement**.
   JavaScript cannot be used to directly detect which option in the contextmenu has selected.

   - When selecting "Open link in new (tab, window)", the page will load in a new tab, window.
   - When not selecting any of these, nothing loads
4. Keyboard:

   - Contextmenu (see 3.)
   - <kbd>Enter</kbd> - See 1.

**How to capture these links**
There is *no reliable* way to capture all link events.

- The `onmouseup` event can be used to detect 1, 2, and 3.
  The used button can be tracked through the `event.button` [(or `event.which`)](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button) property. In all non-IE browsers, 0=Left, 1=Middle, 2=Right. In IE, 1=Left, 2=Middle, 4=Right.
- The `onclick` event can be used to capture 1 and 2.
  The modifier key can be detected through the `event.altKey` and `event.shiftKey` properties.
- The `oncontextmenu` event can be used to capture 3
- The `onkeydown` event can be used to capture 4.

*The behaviour of the modifier keys is not formalized in any specification, and is thus browser-specific. At least Firefox (at least 3+) and Chrome (all?) implement this key behaviour.*

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893269/what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-hide-spoof-the-referrer-in-javascript) - How to intercept an action on a link (`<a>`)?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I guess that the only way to be sure to track a click on an external link is to implement some kind of "redirect page" (as Google and Facebook do).

Comment: Why do you use `onmouseup` instead of `onmousedown`?