# Javascript Event for "Open in new Tab"

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, javascript-framework

I have the following problem: I use Javascript onclick event to change href of a link. It works like a charm but only if user just clicks a link. If "Open in new tab" feature is used for the link - onclick event will not fire and href will never change. Is there any way to handle such an event? Perhaps with jQuery or some other JS Framework?

Example:

```
<a href="some_url" onclick="this.href = 'some_other_url'">Link</a>
```

Comment: Use onmousedown or add oncontextmenu - for inspiration, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893269/what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-hide-spoof-the-referrer-in-javascript ("How to capture links" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927208/catching-event-when-following-a-link)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to change

```
<a href="some_url" onclick="this.href = 'some_other_url'">Link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="some_url" onmousedown="this.href = 'some_other_url'">Link</a>
```

Comment: @FlexJack Did you actually get the "open link in new tab" option to open the `some_other_url` ?

Comment: It's worth noting that `onmmousedown` doesn't fire **on mobile devices** when the user tap-hold the link (to open in new tab). **But it still fires** when the user taps the link.