# How to handle "open in new tab" event?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm developing a service, which renders a series of Resources on a page.
Resource - is a record in database, which has "url" and "visited" fields.

When user click on resource url, it will be marked as "visited: true" in database via sending ajax PUT request.
It works well, until user decides to open url in new tab.
When I open context menu for given url and choose "Open in new Tab", javascript does't catches this event and record in database will not be updated.

In this question [Javascript Event for "Open in new Tab"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365339/javascript-event-for-open-in-new-tab) they adviced to change "click" handler to "onmousedown".
But, this handler catches just opening context menu, even, when I close it, without choosing anything.

Is there any standard way to handle "Open in new tab" event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make resource URLs redirect to your site first (`yoursite.com/record_click?to=actual.url`). When the user clicks the URL, regardless of the way, you can track the URL opening - the AJAX request might not even be needed any more.