# Links that don't pass referrer

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, target, referrer, spoofing

I want to create a list of links opening the targets in new tabs from my private page and I don't want the referring URL to be passed on.
I tried the following method, but it didn't solve the problem:

```
<script>
function op(url){
  window.open(url.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm,''),'_newtab');
}
</script>    
<span onclick="javascript:op(this.innerHTML);">http://www.google.com<span>
```

Is there any way how to spoof or blank the referrer? In the worst case I might create an iframe and put the page with links on some free hosting, but I'd prefer some more elegant solution. The only requirements are tha t it should work in Chrome, Opera, IE and FF (2011+ versions), accessibility is not an issue, since it'll be used by very few users I know.

Comment: As long as you are not being a _naughty_ web developer, you shouldn't need to turn it off...

Comment: @AlexWayne not true. Protecting user's privacy (aka, hiding where they are referred from) isn't naughty at all. For example, a google doc accesses by private URL shouldn't pass the private URL to any page linked to within that doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the easiest is the iframe dirty way.

Answer (score 1):

The referring URL is part of the HTTP protocol, not the mark-up. You can't change this.

Also, you never need to specify `javascript:` in an event handler. It's always is and can only be javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`rel="noreferrer"`](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-link-relations#rel-noreferrer) which is not yet suported by Firefox...

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8957778/22470

Answer (score 0):

Create a tiny app on Heroku that receives a URL then forwards the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to an intermediate page that redirects to the final website, this would hide the true referer.